# Expandables Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, animation, floating-action-button

I found this on the web :[image]

But I can't figured out how to do this... Don't find any library or project like this. If someone can send me the trick, it'll be so usefull !

Thx.

Comment: That is a fantastic UI/UX widget... thanks for showing me this

Comment: Con you post the original link?

Comment: I don't have the post, but I found it on this : https://www.materialup.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the library you're looking for : https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu

Comment: Thanks for the link, I miss this one ! There is a way to modify menu background ?

Comment: Never did it, but the GIF you posted in the question uses this library so it is possible, you just gotta figure it out yourself.